# What is the complexity of intersecting two matrix algebras over a finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity, algebraic-complexity

The following question arose in a joint project with Arkadius Kalka and Adi Ben-Zvi.

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field, and $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ be the $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}$.

For a set of matrices $\mathcal{F}\subseteq M_n(\mathbb{F})$, let
$\mbox{Alg}(\mathcal{F})$ be the subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ generated by $\mathcal{F}$.

Let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\subseteq M_n(\mathbb{F})$ be sets of matrices.

**Question:** Assume that the intersection algebra $\mbox{Alg}(\mathcal{A})\cap \mbox{Alg}(\mathcal{B})$ is much smaller than each of the algebras $\mbox{Alg}(\mathcal{A})$ and
$\mbox{Alg}(\mathcal{B})$.
What is the most efficient way to compute the intersection $\mbox{Alg}(\mathcal{A})\cap \mbox{Alg}(\mathcal{B})$?

Is there a substantially more efficient approach than computing Echelonized bases for the spans (as vector spaces) of the productive semigroups generated by $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ and then solving the appropriate system of linear equations?
(A base can be computed by carrying out, in each step, one multiplication by an element of $\mathcal{A}$ and Echelonizing with respect to the part of the basis available thus far.)

**Comments:** We are, in fact, interested in the following situation. If this helps in finding a better algorithm, that would be just as good.

1. The matrices in $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are invertible.
2. The generated algebras are substantially smaller than $M_n(\mathbb{F})$.
3. "Constants" matter. E.g., an approach 10 times faster is a blessing.

Comment: Is $\mathrm{Alg}(A)$ the same the centralizer of $A?$

Comment: @IgorRivin: If $A$ is a _group_ of matrices (which is the case in our applications), then $\mbox{Alg}(A)=C(C(A))$, where $C(X)$ denotes the centralizer of $X$ in $M_n(\mathbb{F})$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: $A$ and $B$ are _sets_ of matrices, and their cardinality is just their (finite, in our case) size.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I misread $A, B \subseteq M_n(F)$ as $A, B \in M_n(F)$.

Comment: Ah, I misread the same way as @QiaochuYuan...

Comment: In the case $A=B$ this is the same as computing $Alg(A)$, and in the algorithm you describe the bottleneck is the computation of $Alg(A)$ and $Alg(B)$, so you may as well ask first for a better algorithm to compute $Alg(A)$ (I don't know a better algorithm than what you describe).

Comment: @Aurel: Good point. See comments added to the question.

Comment: @BoazTsaban From your answer to Igor's comment it seems that $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $M_n(F)$. If so, it is important to mention it since representation theory might be useful. In you case, are their cardinalities divisible by the characteristic of $F$? More generally, do you assume that $Alg(A)$ and $Alg(B)$ act completely reducibly on $F^n$?

Comment: @Aurel: See Comment 1 in the question. I think that in our applications, the characteristic of the field _does_ divide the order of the generated groups.

Comment: Computational representation theory of groups is harder than linear algebra (this is a metatheorem :-)). My bet is that in general there cannot be a speedup hoped for in the question.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Definitely mathematically harder, but often gives algorithms that are more efficient than the straightforward linear algebra algorithms. And we do not care here about often, of course, but about the specific question at hand. :)

Comment: The only hope seems to be to compute (partial) decompositions (using Meataxe, see e.g. http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~mareg/download/papers/bham_95/bham_95.pdf) of the representations of the groups generated by $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, and hope they have small factors only. Then linear algebra becomes faster.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I read the article you link to, and it seems like what we need, in terms of complxities mentioned there. However, I do not see the full picture. Any chance to post here a detailed description, as an answer (not a comment)?